# Getting error in the vbscript

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I want to test the existence of a particular file on a path through VB Script inside Powershell
but getting error as-

"C:\Users\broy5\Desktop\test.vbs(3, 21) Microsoft VBScript compilation error: Inv
alid character"

Below is my code:

```
$path  ="C:\fso\test.txt"
if((Test-Path -Path $path))
{
new-item -Path $path -Value "ARUN" –itemtype file
}
else
{
Add-Content -Path $path -Value "`r`n Additional content"
}
```

Please correct me where I'm wrong and let me know the right code.

Thanks

Comment: So what's on the `test.vbs` line 3, char 21? That's what is generating the error.

Comment: Please show your *VBScript* code and explain how it's related to the PowerShell code you posted.